# Switch Statement and While Loop

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, do-while

I am writing a database program that allows the user to search for employees and it opens up a menu for them.in my Main() I have to prompt the User to press m to open up the menu() or q to open up finalStats() any other input is invalid. My problem is that i can't get a while loop to work properly. whenever i hit m it works and when i hit q it works fine, but whenever i hit a key other than those there's an infinite loop and it just infinitely prints out "Please enter a valid character"

```
boolean end = false;
    System.out.println("Enter m or M to open menu, otherwise enter q or Q for the final stats");
    String entered = scan.next();
    while (end == false)
    switch(entered)
    {
    case "m":
    case "M":
        menu();
    case "q":
    case "Q":
        finalStats();
        end = true;
    default:
        System.err.println("Please enter a valid character");
    }
```

Comment: `while (end == false)` is better written as `while (!end)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the line

```
while (end == false)
```

to before the `scan.next()`, to allow the user to try again. Make sure to add braces when you do this, so the `while` affects the entire program snippet you are showing. It is considered a good practice to always use curly braces for loops and if statements.

Also, as @RahulTripathi points out, you need to add `break` statements at the end of your `case` blocks.

Comment: Wow i'm so stupid, haha Thanks man it's working properly now thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `break` statement in your `switch case`. Also move your `while` statement to allow user to scan.

Try this:

```
boolean end = false;
while (end == false)
    System.out.println("Enter m or M to open menu, otherwise enter q or Q for the final stats");
    String entered = scan.next();

    switch(entered)
    {
    case "m":
    case "M":
        menu(); 
        break;
    case "q":
    case "Q":
        finalStats();
        end = true;
        break;
    default:
        System.err.println("Please enter a valid character");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this fixes your problems:

```
boolean end = false;
System.out.println("Enter m or M to open menu, otherwise enter q or Q for the final stats");
String entered = scan.next();
while (end == false)
{
switch(entered)
    {
    case "m":
    case "M":
        menu();
        break;
    case "q":
    case "Q":
        finalStats();
        end = true;
        break;
    default:
        System.err.println("Please enter a valid character");
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter m or M to open menu, otherwise enter q or Q for the final                     stats");
    String entered = scan.next();
}
```

You have a couple of problems. You are missing `break;` in your cases and you are not soliciting new input inside of the while loop. I am not sure exactly what you are doing whether you want to solicit an option more than once.